# Transit visa for Uzbekistan passenger

Tags: visas, transit, australia, transit-visas, uzbek-citizens

My passenger is flying from Uzbekistan to New Zealand and has to change planes in Australia. He has a work visa but no transit visa. Is this allowed? I know Russians cannot transit in Australia, but I'm not sure of the situation for Uzbekistan citizens.

Comment: as always with such questions, ask the appropriate (in this case Australian) consulate or embassy.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually rather simple.  Australia has very well defined rules for transiting through without a visa.  You can review the [list of countries that this is allowed for](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/no-visa.htm) on the Immigration Service site.

Once reviewed you can see that Uzbekistan is not one of the countries that transit is visa less unless the passenger is a holder of a diplomatic passport.